# When are computed the functions inside an Enum's variable?

Tags: java, enums, compilation, runtime

Consider the following code :

```
public enum MyOwnEnum    {

    JANVIER("janvier", "3101"),
    FEVRIER("février", new DateCalculator().getLeapYear()),
    MARS("mars", "3103"),
    AVRIL("avril", "3004");

    // Two variables, the protected constructor, getters

}
```

How would the code behave ? Would the method be computed directly at compile time and fixed, or would it be computed each time someone calls `FEVRIER` through `MyOwnEnum.FEVRIER` or `MyOwnEnum.valueOf("FEVRIER")` ? Or fixed, but at runtime ?

Comment: Worth a read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: What method? There is nothing here but constructors.

Comment: `FEVRIER("février", new DateCalculator().getLeapYear())`. Here, `getLeapYear()` is a method, not a constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The enum constants are created once at runtime, or more specifically, at class-loading time.

Consider the following code:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    ONE("One at " + System.nanoTime()),
    TWO("Two at " + System.nanoTime());

    String value;

    TestEnum(String value) {
        System.out.println(value);
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Loading");

        Class.forName("TestEnum"); // Load class

        System.out.println("Evaluating");

        System.out.println(TestEnum.ONE.value); // Evaluate value one
        System.out.println(TestEnum.TWO.value); // Evaluate value two
    }
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
Loading
One at 31207575500045
Two at 31207575625697
Evaluating
One at 31207575500045
Two at 31207575625697
```

Note that the values don't change on subsequent invocations.

Comment: Clear and simple. Thank you !

Comment: If you replace `"One"` and `"Two"` by `System.nanoTime()+""` you will get the time of the creation. Every further call of `TestEnum.ONE.value` will then return the same time. +1 for this simple illustration

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the byte code generated by your `ENUM` you can see that the above code is similar as below code:

```
class MyOwnEnum{
    public static MyOwnEnum JANVIER = new MyOwnEnum("janvier", "3101");
    public static MyOwnEnum FEVRIER = new MyOwnEnum(("février", new DateCalculator().getLeapYear()));
    public static MyOwnEnum MARS = new MyOwnEnum("mars", "3103");
}
```

That means your code will create the Object of `DateCalculator(`) and call `getLeapYear()` when it will **init the static variable FEVRIER**  and maintain all properties of static variable:

> 1. A static variable which belongs to the class and not to object(instance)
> 2. Static variables are initialized only once , at the start of the execution.
> 3. Static variables will be initialized first, before the initialization of any instance variables
> 4. A single copy to be shared by all instances of the class
> 5. A static variable can be accessed directly by the class name and doesn’t need any object.

As `FEVRIER` is a static variable `public static MyOwnEnum FEVRIER = new MyOwnEnum(("février", new DateCalculator().getLeapYear()));` this lines of code will execute only once per class loader loaded the class.

Here is the byte code for reference:

```
21: ldc           #26                 // String FEVRIER
      23: iconst_1
      24: ldc           #27                 // String fΘvrier
      26: new           #29                 // class com/java8/demo/DateCalculator
      29: dup
      30: invokespecial #31                 // Method com/java8/demo/DateCalculator."<init>":()V
      33: invokevirtual #33                 // Method com/java8/demo/DateCalculator.getLeapYear:()Ljava/lang/String;
      36: invokespecial #20                 // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
      39: putstatic     #37                 // Field FEVRIER:Lcom/java8/demo/MyOwnEnum;
      42: new           #1                  // class com/java8/demo/MyOwnEnum
      45: dup
      46: ldc           #39                 // String MARS
      48: iconst_2
      49: ldc           #40                 // String mars
      51: ldc           #42                 // String 3103
      53: invokespecial #20                 // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
      56: putstatic     #44                 // Field MARS:Lcom/java8/demo/MyOwnEnum;
      59: new           #1                  // class com/java8/demo/MyOwnEnum
```